# Can't get Request.QueryString or similar methods to work

Tags: c#, iis-7, cgi, request.querystring

To my shame, because I can barely C#, I cannot manage to read the parameters from the URL.

I run a C# cgi executable on my IIS 7 as an application. The url that calls the executable is as below:

> https://server/cgi/showEmail/showEmail.exe?email=john@gmail.com

The code starts as below:

```
using System;
using System.Web; // <---- isn't this for Request.QueryString ?
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class showEmail
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("\r\n\r\n");
        Console.WriteLine("<h1>Test</h1>");

        try
        {
```

Now, if I use the code below, the program compiles, but gives this a null exception when executed in the browser:

```
        string email = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["email"];
```

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at showEmail.Main(String[] args)

and if I use this code below, the fun stops already at the compiler, who gives a "current context" exception:

```
       string email = Request.QueryString["email"];
```

> error CS0103: The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context

...

Am I missing something elementary that is required for the executable to see the url parameters?

Edit: I have looked through sof and many other places, but so far have not been able to connect the dots on this issue.

Comment: I'm in the same boat with you — I'm very new to C# Razor and cannot seem to figure out why Request.QueryString doesn't work.  I've been searching for over two hours and cannot seem to find what collection is required, and the variety of ways available to evaluate query string properties.  Everything I've seen (and tried) doesn't work because of this very reason that it does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current.Request` is not available in console appliaction.

Use args parameter to receive query string parameter, like I am doing below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("parameter[{0}] is [{1}]", i, args[i]);
}
```

You might need to use below code to extract parameters from url received in args.

```
var url=args[0];

var queryString = url.Substring(url.IndexOf('?')).Split('#')[0]
System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString)
```

Comment: Thank's for pointing me to the right direction. Unfortunately, using your suggestion, the length of args is 0, so either my IIS is filtering the query string before they reach the application or there is some other problem still to be discovered in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work finally, please keep in mind this is not professionally validated code, more of try and try and try...

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email = Request.QueryString["email"] ?? "null";
        if (email != "null") {
```